# kafka-stream aggregation on multiple inputs with cogroup and filter

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to implement a kafka-stream aggregation on multiple (4) input topics.

Let's the topics are: A, B, C, D;

The topology should:

- pull 2 single messages from A and B, apply the aggregation, apply a filter, store on KTable
- pull N messages from C and D, apply the aggregation, store on KTable

The Aggregator code is not provided, but the behaviour is:

- message from B contains a value, we call X
- n messages from C and D are handled as counters increment, and the aggregated object should do +1 to counter from C and +1 to counter from D and the final
- the filter should verify that X = C_counter + D_counter
- when the equation is verified, store on KTable
- finally do something after filter/storage

Here the code snippet:

```
private Topology buildTopology() {
    StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();

    // create the 4 streams, reading strings
    KStream<String, String> streamA_AsString = streamsBuilder.stream(DemoTopic_A);
    KStream<String, String> streamC_AsString = streamsBuilder.stream(DemoTopic_C);
    KStream<String, String> streamB_AsString = streamsBuilder.stream(DemoTopic_B);
    KStream<String, String> streamD_AsString = streamsBuilder.stream(DemoTopic_D);

    // map the strings to java object (the entity used for aggregation)
    KStream<String, DemoEntity> streamA = streamA_AsString.map(demoKeyValueMapper);
    KStream<String, DemoEntity> streamC = streamC_AsString.map(demoKeyValueMapper);
    KStream<String, DemoEntity> streamB = streamB_AsString.map(demoKeyValueMapper);
    KStream<String, DemoEntity> streamD = streamD_AsString.map(demoKeyValueMapper);

    // group the message/object by key
    final KGroupedStream<String, DemoEntity> streamA_Grouped = streamA.groupByKey();
    final KGroupedStream<String, DemoEntity> streamProgressGrouped = streamC.groupByKey();
    final KGroupedStream<String, DemoEntity> streamPushingGrouped = streamB.groupByKey();
    final KGroupedStream<String, DemoEntity> streamErrorGrouped = streamD.groupByKey();

    // instance the aggregator
    DemoAggregator demoAggregator = new DemoAggregator();

    // build the aggregation chain
    // using cogroup to group previous kgrouped, providing the aggregator
    streamA_Grouped
        .cogroup(demoAggregator)
        .cogroup(streamProgressGrouped, demoAggregator)
        .cogroup(streamPushingGrouped, demoAggregator)
        .cogroup(streamErrorGrouped, demoAggregator)
        // provide the initializer
        .aggregate(demoInitializer)
        // apply the filter and, at same time, store into KTable
        .filter(isCompleted, Named.as(DemoCompletionStorageTableName))
        // transform to stateless KStream for further usage
        // from here, no more stateful by changelog
        .toStream()
        .foreach((key, value) -> {
            // use values
            log.info("here we would use values for: { key:{}, message:{} }", () -> key, () -> value);
        });

    return streamsBuilder.build();
}
```

Unfortunately the topology won't start, and this is the error:

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: Processor COGROUPKSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000008-repartition-filter is already added.

It seems it already added that COGROUPKSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000008-repartition-filter into an object NodeFactory, and so the exception.
The class from Kafka dependency is "InternalTopologyBuilder", on method "addProcessor".

Searching on Google that error string I found only the source code of KafkaStreams... no other stackoverflow question, nor forum, nothing....

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Late response but got the same error, went through it by giving a unique name to each `groupByKey() (Grouped.with())` so each underlying processor has a unique name:

Like:

```
final KGroupedStream<String, DemoEntity> streamA_Grouped = streamA.groupByKey(Grouped.with("GROUP_BY_A", Serdes.String(), CustomSerdes.getSerdes()));
final KGroupedStream<String, DemoEntity> streamProgressGrouped = streamC.groupByKey(Grouped.with("GROUP_BY_PROGRESS", Serdes.String(), CustomSerdes.getSerdes()));
final KGroupedStream<String, DemoEntity> streamPushingGrouped = streamB.groupByKey(Grouped.with("GROUP_BY_PUSHING", Serdes.String(), CustomSerdes.getSerdes()));
final KGroupedStream<String, DemoEntity> streamErrorGrouped = streamD.groupByKey(Grouped.with("GROUP_BY_ERROR", Serdes.String(), CustomSerdes.getSerdes()));
```